# find a vector field in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with specific properties

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, exterior-derivative

Let $α = dz - ydx \in Ω^1 (\mathbb{R}^3)$

Find a vector field Z  in $\mathbb{R^3}$ such that $α(Z) = 1$ and $dα(Z,.) = 0$

What I did:

I computed $d\alpha = dx \wedge dy $.
Then let $Z=a\partial_x + b\partial_y +c\partial_z $ be a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$

We have  $α(Z) = 1 \Rightarrow c\partial_z - ya\partial_x = 1 $  **(I)**

and $dα(Z,.) = 0 \Rightarrow dx \wedge dy (a\partial_x + b\partial_y +c\partial_z\ ,\ .)$.

but we have $ dx \wedge dy (a\partial_x) =  dx(a \partial_x)dy(.) -dx(.)dy(a \partial_x) = ady(.)$

and $ dx \wedge dy (b\partial_y) =  dx(b \partial_y)dy(.) -dx(.)dy(b \partial_y) = -bdx(.)$

and  $ dx \wedge dy (b\partial_y) =  0$

which means finally
$ ady(.) = bdx(.) $    **(II)**

Could we find a,b and c from the two results (I) and (II)?

Thank you!

Comment: (II) means that $a=b=0$,, while (I) is wrong; you get that $c-ay=1$. Hence the vector field you are looking for is $Z=\partial_z$.

Comment: Indeed, $\alpha(Z) \in \mathbb{R}$. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @Dog_69 , the first equation should read as $c-ya=1$. Now you derived (II) correctly (although in a slightly complicated way), but since $dx$ and $dy$ are linearly independent in each point, (II) implies $a=b=0$, so (I) reduces to $c=1$. So you get the solution $Z=\partial_z$ which is readily seen to be correct.

Comment: How would you derive (II) in easier way? I am new to this field of differential forms. Thank you!

Comment: It dosen't make much difference, but you can say directly that $(dx\wedge dy)(X,\underline{\ })=dx(Z)dy-dy(Z)dx$ so inserting, you readily get $ady-bdx$.